# Redirect input / output console cmd

Tags: vb6, cmd, pipe

I have the following code of my authorship using "Pipes" to create a console, my question is is possible to use an alternative to the "Pipes"?

Greetings: D

```
' ****************************************************************************************************************************** '
'
' --- Autor: Jhonjhon_123 (Jhon Jairo Pro Developer)
' --- Versión: 1.0
' --- Descripción: Shell a nivel local en windows
' --- Fallos y Mejoras: MSN; j.j.g.p@hotmail.com
' --- Licencia: GNU General Public License
'
' ****************************************************************************************************************************** '
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function PeekNamedPipe Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hNamedPipe As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nBufferSize As Long, lpBytesRead As Long, lpTotalBytesAvail As Long, lpBytesLeftThisMessage As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, lpOverlapped As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long, ByVal lpOverlapped As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As Long, phWritePipe As Long, lpPipeAttributes As Any, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DuplicateHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSourceProcessHandle As Long, ByVal hSourceHandle As Long, ByVal hTargetProcessHandle As Long, lpTargetHandle As Long, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwOptions As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES          As Long = &H100
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW          As Long = &H1
Private Const DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS         As Long = &H2
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS         As Long = &H20


Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength                                As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor                   As Long
    bInheritHandle                         As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb                                     As Long
    lpReserved                             As String
    lpDesktop                              As String
    lpTitle                                As String
    dwX                                    As Long
    dwY                                    As Long
    dwXSize                                As Long
    dwYSize                                As Long
    dwXCountChars                          As Long
    dwYCountChars                          As Long
    dwFillAttribute                        As Long
    dwFlags                                As Long
    wShowWindow                            As Integer
    cbReserved2                            As Integer
    lpReserved2                            As Long
    hStdInput                              As Long
    hStdOutput                             As Long
    hStdError                              As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess                               As Long
    hThread                                As Long
    dwProcessID                            As Long
    dwThreadId                             As Long
End Type

Dim lHInput As Long
Dim lHOutput As Long
Dim lCmdID As Long

Public Sub StopShell()

If lHInput > 0 Then Call CloseHandle(lHInput)

If lHOutput > 0 Then Call CloseHandle(lHOutput)

If lCmdID > 0 Then Call TerminateProcess(lCmdID, ByVal 0&): Call CloseHandle(lCmdID)

End Sub

Public Function GetOutTextShell(sOut As String) As Boolean
Dim bBuffer() As Byte
Dim lLen As Long
Dim bRes As Boolean
Dim lLenBuff As Long

bRes = CBool(PeekNamedPipe(lHOutput, 0&, 0&, 0&, lLen, 0&))

If Not bRes Then Exit Function

If lLen <= 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim bBuffer(lLen)

If ReadFile(lHOutput, bBuffer(0), lLen, lLenBuff, ByVal 0&) = 0 Then Exit Function

sOut = Left(StrConv(bBuffer, vbUnicode), lLenBuff)

GetOutTextShell = True

End Function

Public Sub SendToShell(sCMD As String)
Dim sBytes() As Byte
Dim BytesWritten As Long

If lHInput = 0 Then Exit Sub
sCMD = sCMD & vbNewLine
sBytes = StrConv(sCMD, vbFromUnicode)

If WriteFile(lHInput, ByVal sCMD, Len(sCMD), BytesWritten, 0&) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Public Function StartShell() As Boolean
On Error GoTo Error

Dim tSecurityAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tStartInfo          As STARTUPINFO
Dim tProcessInfo        As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim lCurrentID          As Long

lCurrentID = GetCurrentProcess()

With tStartInfo
    .cb = Len(tStartInfo)
    .dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES Or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
End With

With tSecurityAttributes
    .nLength = Len(tSecurityAttributes)
    .bInheritHandle = 1
End With

If CreatePipe(lHOutput, tStartInfo.hStdOutput, tSecurityAttributes, 0) = 0 Then
    GoTo Error
End If

If CreatePipe(tStartInfo.hStdInput, lHInput, tSecurityAttributes, 0) = 0 Then
    GoTo Error
End If

If DuplicateHandle(lCurrentID, tStartInfo.hStdOutput, lCurrentID, tStartInfo.hStdError, 0&, True, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) = 0 Then
    GoTo Error
End If

If CreateProcess(vbNullString, "cmd", tSecurityAttributes, tSecurityAttributes, 1, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, ByVal 0&, vbNullString, tStartInfo, tProcessInfo) = 0 Then
    GoTo Error
End If

With tProcessInfo
    Call CloseHandle(.hThread)

    lCmdID = .hProcess

    If .dwProcessID > 0 And .hProcess > 0 Then
        StartShell = True
    Else
        GoTo Error
    End If
End With

Exit Function
Error:
Call StopShell
StartShell = False

End Function
```

Code Full Example: http://www.multiupload.com/1NVDU8LZSP

Comment: You have to use pipes. Take a look at this helper class: http://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/cExec.zip

Comment: @wqw thank you very much for this class will guide me!, but definitely there is no alternative to the "Pipes"?

Comment: What is wrong with Pipes?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My idea is to make the code as small as possible, I have seen this same thing using "socks", but requires a client, ask why there is a local alternative?